# Can I put Ubuntu on an ASUS VivoBook F202?

Tags: asus, touchscreen

I'm looking to buy an ASUS VivoBook F202 with an i3 processor. Will I be able to put Ubuntu on it, especially with the touch function? Has anybody done that yet?

Ta muchly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dual booting into Ubuntu 13.10 along with Windows 8.1 on my F202E, and it's running pretty well.

With the standard installation, the touchscreen works. But it seems to work more like a touchpad. i.e. the touch inputs are scaled over the entire available display space. This becomes an issue when you're trying to use it when connected to an external monitor, but otherwise it's usable.